Jackson Annotations not working in Spring Boot
I'm encountering a challenge with Jackson annotations in my User class while managing a self-referencing @ManyToMany relationship. Despite applying the appropriate annotations, Jackson fails to handle the relationship correctly. When I retrieve the User entity, the followers and following fields enter a recursive loop, leading to an infinite cycle of references.
Here’s the User entity:
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;
import com.pubfinder.pubfinder.models.enums.Role;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * The type User.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.UUIDGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private Role role;

    @ManyToMany(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH}
    )
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_following",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "following_id")
    )
    @Builder.Default
    @JsonManagedReference
    Set<User> following = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(
            mappedBy = "following",
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH}
    )
    @Builder.Default
    @JsonBackReference
    Set<User> followers = new HashSet<>();

    @PreRemove
    private void cleanupFollowerRelationshipsBeforeDeletion() {
        for (User user : this.following) {
            user.getFollowers().remove(this);
        }
    }

    public void addFollowing(User user) {
        if (!this.following.contains(user)) {
            this.following.add(user);
            user.getFollowers().add(this);
        }
    }

    public void removeFollowing(User user) {
        if (this.following.contains(user)) {
            this.following.remove(user);
            user.getFollowers().remove(this);
        }
    }

    // Getters and Setters......
}

Dependencies:
Here are the main dependencies in my build.gradle file:
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.15.4")
implementation("org.projectlombok:lombok")
annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")
testImplementation("com.h2database:h2")

Jackson should handle the bidirectional relationships using @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference correctly, and the serialization/deserialization process should avoid infinite recursion.
I have also tried @JsonIdentityInfo and @JsonIgnore, but nothing seems to work.
This is how I want the output to look:
{
  "id": "1",
  "username": "user1",
  "following": [
    {
      "id": "2",
      "username": "user2",
      "following": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "username": "user1",
          "following": [ /* infinite nesting */ ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

This how I want it to look:
{
  "id": "1",
  "username": "user1",
  "following": [
    { "id": "2", "username": "user2" }
  ],
  "followers": [
    { "id": "3", "username": "user3" }
  ]
}


Did you try to use DTO? It should give you full control over the JSON structure and help  to get rid of infinite recursion by flattening relationships. You will need to add a UserDTO class and a UserMapper class for converting User to UserDTO and back.

The latter can be easily achieved using MapStruct.

I already have a mapper in my project, but I would like to try to make the Jackson annotations work.

Here is the solution shown below
Using DTOs (Data Transfer Objects) is an effective way to handle self-referencing relationships in your User entity and avoid infinite recursion during serialization.
1 ) Create DTO Classes
UserBasicDTO.java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserBasicDTO {
    private UUID id;
    private String username;

    public static UserBasicDTO fromEntity(User user) {
        return new UserBasicDTO(
            user.getId(),
            user.getUsername()
        );
    }
}

UserDTO.java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserDTO {
    private UUID id;
    private String username;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;

    private Set<UserBasicDTO> following;
    private Set<UserBasicDTO> followers;

    public static UserDTO fromEntity(User user) {
        return new UserDTO(
            user.getId(),
            user.getUsername(),
            user.getFirstname(),
            user.getLastname(),
            user.getEmail(),
            user.getFollowing().stream()
                .map(UserBasicDTO::fromEntity)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet()),
            user.getFollowers().stream()
                .map(UserBasicDTO::fromEntity)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet())
        );
    }
}

2 ) Define UserService
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public UserDTO getUserById(UUID id) {
        return userRepository.findById(id)
                .map(UserDTO::fromEntity)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("User not found"));
    }


    public List<UserDTO> getAllUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll().stream()
                .map(UserDTO::fromEntity)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}

3 ) Define Controller
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;

    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> getUser(@PathVariable UUID id) {
        UserDTO userDTO = userService.getUserById(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userDTO);
    }


    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<UserDTO>> getAllUsers() {
        List<UserDTO> users = userService.getAllUsers();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(users);
    }

}


I gave up on Jackson annotations, used a DTO, and it worked perfectly. Thanks!
